# Remove Files Based on Users Input - Bash Scripting

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I want to be able to remove files based on the user's input. I have a list of files and directories numbered like shown below. I want the user to be able to select any number to delete the corresponding file. For example, if the user enters 2, DirectoryA will be removed (assuming they have permission). Basically, I want to match the number that the user inputs with the file and remove the file.

Here is what my code shows:

```
1. Directory1
2. DirectoryA
3. DirectoryB
4. Directory_C
---
5. File1
6. FileA
7. FileB
8. File_C
Please enter index of a file or directory to remove:
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if  [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; then
   cd "$1" 2> /dev/null
   if [[ $? = 1 ]]; then
      echo "Please enter a valid directory."
   else
         Dir="TRUE"

         i=0
         c=( $(ls --group-directories-first $*) )
         count=0;

         for f in ${c[@]}; do
            if [[ ${Dir} == "TRUE" && ! -d ${f} ]]; then
               echo ---
               Dir="FALSE"
            fi
         echo "$((++count)). $f";
         done
   fi
   echo "Please enter index of a file to remove: "
   read input
else
    Dir="TRUE"

         i=0
         c=( $(ls --group-directories-first $*) )
        count=0;

         for f in ${c[@]}; do
            if [[ ${Dir} == "TRUE" && ! -d ${f} ]]; then
echo ---
               Dir="FALSE"
            fi
         echo "$((++count)). $f";
         done
   fi
   echo "Please enter index of a file to remove: "
   read input
```

Comment: Use the `select` built in. This is what it was made for.

Comment: You've stated what you want, and shown some code that you've written...but what's the question?

Comment: I have to comment on the absurdity of `cd "$1" 2> /dev/null; if [[ $? = 1 ]]; then echo "useless error message"`  By redirecting the error of cd to /dev/null, you are throwing away a useful error message and replacing it with a useless one!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Add necesary operations in each case to remove directory and file.

```
read NUM
case $NUM in
1) echo "Removing directory1 (Add remove operations here instead of echo)" ;;
2) echo "Removing directoryA (Add remove operations here instead of echo)" ;;
#...
8) echo "Removing fileC (Add remove operations here instead of echo)" ;;
*) echo "Invalid index number!" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using the bash `select` builtin (as  Etan Reisner already mentioned). Here is an example:

```
S3="Choose file or directory to delete: "

select FILENAME in *;
do
        rm -rf $FILENAME
        exit 0
done
```